# Java File operation query

Tags: java, io, java-io

I am trying to solve the following problem.

1. I have two directories. Lets say /x and /y.
2. I want all File read operations to happen in /x and all write operations will happen in /y. Lets say if a java program is trying to read a file /a/b.xml using File API, it should directly go to /x and search for /x/a/b/c. Similarly if a program is trying to write /a/b.xml, it should directly write to /y.

Is it possible to implement in Java?

Comment: So construct thenfilenames accordingly. What exactly is the problem? NB The connection with NIO escapes me.

Answer (score 0):

```
public File getFileToReadFrom(String suffix) {
    return new File("/x" + suffix);
}

public File getFileToWriteTo(String suffix) {
    return new File("/y" + suffix);
}
```

These methods could also return an InputStream and an OutputStream, or a Reader and a Writer, depending on what you want to read/write.

If you want to automatically make all existing writes to any file go to `/x` and all existing reads from any file go to `/y`, then no, that's not possible.

Comment: Actually what I want is some kind of "interceptor" that can redirect the read and write operations without the program being aware of it. Can we have one such interceptor per JVM? Can we use custom FileSystemProvider for that purpose?

Comment: No, that's not possible.